# assigning variable inside jquery on or javascript bind

Tags: javascript, jquery

Short question, how can I more efficiently write below code so I don't repeatedly assign the parent variable a new value?

Is this bind function the same as using object literals?

```
function bindAuthorPopup() {
        $(".insight-author").on({
            mouseenter: function (event) {
                var parent = $(this).parent('div').find('.popup-content');
                parent.toggleClass('show');
            },
            mouseleave: function (event) {
                var parent = $(this).parent('div').find('.popup-content');
                parent.toggleClass('show');
            },            
        });
    }
```

Comment: mouseenter and mouseleave both looks same?

Comment: You can create a function so that you only have to do `var parent = getParent(this);`. But there is nothing you can do to avoid creating `parent` in each handler, since `this` might refer to different elements. Of course if you are doing exactly the same in both handlers, just define the function once and use it for both events.

Answer (score 3):

You can do something like this:

```
function bindAuthorPopup() {
    $(".insight-author").each(function() {
        var elem = $(this);
        var parent = elem.parent('div').find('.popup-content');
        elem.on({
            mouseenter: function (event) {
                parent.toggleClass('show');
            },
            mouseleave: function (event) {
                parent.toggleClass('show');
            },
        });       
    });
}
```

This works even if the callbacks are different. If they're always the same, then you can use what @sh1da9440 wrote.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass space-separated event types to the "on" method.

```
function bindAuthorPopup() {
    $(".insight-author").on('mouseenter mouseleave', function (event) {
        var parent = $(this).parent('div').find('.popup-content');
        parent.toggleClass('show');
    });
}
```